# Redis transaction with condition

Tags: redis

I want to do something like the following:

Step 1: check Redis server for value x, which indicates free space left on that Redis server
Step 2: if x > some number, do a transaction on Redis server.

I am wondering if step 1 and 2 can be atomic as well. This is because multiple clients could be issuing these two steps, and if 1 and 2 are not atomic, then presumably two clients can both execute step 1, satisfied with x, and then both do step 2, which I do not want.

Is there a good way to do this? I am using the Python Redis client.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at lua? https://redis.com/ebook/part-3-next-steps/chapter-11-scripting-redis-with-lua/  if you want finer control and atomicity